# RTL8188FU driver couldn't be installed because of a missing kernel tree module?

Tags: driver, archlinux

I am relatively new to Arch Linux.

So i have been dealing with this issue for quite a long time now. I got this new RTL8188FTV  wireless USB network adapter and i have tried installing the drivers for it with Paru AUR helper. The installation seems to fail, as it throws this error at the end :

```
==> ERROR: Missing 5.15.70-1-lts kernel modules tree for module 8188fu/r112.89d7288.
```

I can confirm the wireless adapter is functional, since it works on Windows
Package Name: 8188fu-kelebek333-dkms-git

Is there a way to install this "kernel modules tree" so i could finish the installation?
Thanks!

Edit: back with more errors

```
Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=6.0.5-arch1-1.............(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.5-arch1-1 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8188fu/r113.f5df53d/build/make.log for more information.
error: command failed to execute correctly
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/3) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
(2/3) Install DKMS modules
==> dkms install --no-depmod 8188fu/r113.f5df53d -k 6.0.5-arch1-1
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.5-arch1-1 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8188fu/r113.f5df53d/build/make.log for more information.
==> WARNING: `dkms install --no-depmod 8188fu/r113.f5df53d -k 6.0.5-arch1-1' exited 10
==> ERROR: Missing 5.15.75-1-lts kernel modules tree for module 8188fu/r113.f5df53d.
(3/3) Performing snapper post snapshots for the following configurations...
```

The command

```
echo 'alias usb:v0BDApF179d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin* rtl8188fu' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8188eu-blacklist.conf
```

doesn't seem to do much.
Installation still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your on kernel 5.15 so you have to backlist the rl8188eu driver. You can do that with this command

```
echo 'alias usb:v0BDApF179d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin* rtl8188fu' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8188eu-blacklist.conf
```

The code was taken from the same repo the aur package was made from
https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu

Comment: thank you for your answer. it looks like the driver started magically working after i updated my system. i am going to mark this as the solution, as this might help other people facing the same issue.

Comment: Update: when i updated my system again, the driver stopped working. i tried the command and reinstalled the driver. it still doesn't work. :(